# Match specific word with grep -e

Tags: grep, expression

I am trying to use grep to print only lines that start with a specific pattern. Here is an example

```
$SERVER_IP = 2.2.2.2
$SERVER_IP_PORT = 1111
$SERVER_IP_XXX = blablabla
```

I want grep to print only SERVER_IP = 2.2.2.2 and not the other three lines.

I tried the command below but it did not work

```
grep -e "^\s*\$SERVER_IP$"
```

If I try:

```
grep -e "^\s*\$SERVER_IP"
```

grep will print all three lines

How can I accomplish this using grep -e or egrep? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -e "^\s*\$SERVER_IP\>"
```

The `\>` means "word-boundary", or "place where word characters meet non-word characters."

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. Is that word-boundery the same in sed and other tools that use reg exp? I thought it was $

Comment: `$` means "end-of-line".  The word-boundary expression does exist in all POSIX regexes.  In PCREs, they use `\b` instead.

Comment: then why this expression "^\s*\$DB\['TYPE'\]\>" does not work to print $DB['TYPE']? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use grep -e '^\$SERVER_IP =' to match any line that starts with $SERVER_IP =

Answer (score 0):

If you have `awk`, you can do:

```
awk '$1=="$SERVER_IP"' file
$SERVER_IP = 2.2.2.2
```

The `==` makes it match only while field `1` is exact `$SERVER_IP`